# Programmatically getting list of goals triggered through xConnect for certain contact

Tags: xconnect, goals

I would like to get check whether certain goal was triggered through xConnect for certain contact programmatically. We are using `Sitecore 9.0.1`.

I have found this article:
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/get-interactions/get-events.html#get-events-by-definition-id

But it is unclear which ID I should use on this line:

```
Sitecore.XConnect.InteractionReference interactionRef = new Sitecore.XConnect.InteractionReference(contactRef, Guid.Parse("DA2DA5F0-4348-E611-82E7-34E6D7117DCB"));
```

Id `DA2DA5F0-4348-E611-82E7-34E6D7117DCB` is Id of what?

It is an Id of Interaction that is stored in DB?

How can I get it via xConnect API?

I just want to check whether goal what trigger for contact

Comment: Do we have any idea what `DA2DA5F0-4348-E611-82E7-34E6D7117DCB` is in reference to?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is coming from [xdb_collection].[Interactions] table from one of the shard dbs and it's [InteractionId] @ChrisAuer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer after going through xConnect documentation more thoroughly.

Here is the code that you can use to get all goals for contact:

```
using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var contactID = Guid.Parse("ea991dce-1f9b-443c-84a5-f83b46cbc0f8");

                // IMPORTANT: You cannot check facets for null; check a property of the facet instead, such as SiteName for WebVisit
                var queryable = client.Interactions
                    .Where(x => x.Contact.Id == contactID
                    && x.Events.OfType<Goal>().Any())
                    .WithExpandOptions(new InteractionExpandOptions(WebVisit.DefaultFacetKey) { Contact = new RelatedContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey) });

                var enumerator = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(10);

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    foreach (var item in enumerator.Current)
                    {
                        var listOfGoals = item.Events.OfType<Goal>();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
```

Add these two nuget packages to your project to resolve all assembly conflicts:

```
<package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="System.Interactive.Async.Providers" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
```

More details here:
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect//xconnect-client-api/contacts/get-contacts/get-contact-interactions.html#filtering-interactions