# How to programmatically trigger a goal to contact and then retrieve it in the same visit and in later visits

Tags: xdb, xconnect, goals, contact

I want to trigger a goal programmatically to the website visitor/contact and retrieve this triggered goal during the contact's current visit and in his future visits. I could trigger the goal of using `CurrentPage.Register()` method under `Analytics.Tracker` API, but how can I retrieve this goal in the same session and future sessions?

Please help. Thanks!

**EDIT:** It is not clear how to check whether the current contact is a new contact or an existing contact. Looks like `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew` behaves inconsistently

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/programmatically-getting-list-of-goals-triggered-through-xconnect-for-certain-co?rq=1 didn't help..

Answer (score 2):

Goals of the current visit (interaction) are stored in the session and can be retrieved using Tracker API:

```
List<PageEventData> pageGoals = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.Pages
                                .SelectMany(p => p.PageEvents)
                                .Where(evt => evt.IsGoal)
                                .ToList();
```

To retrieve goals of previous interactions you can use xConnect (SE question that you mentioned) or KeyBehaviourCache:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<KeyBehaviorCacheEntry> contactGoals = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.KeyBehaviorCache.Goals;
```

If you want to personalize based on the fact that a specific goal was triggered during current or past interactions consider using Sitecore rules condition: */sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Visit/Goal was triggered during a past or current interaction*